# Array Jquery in function

Tags: jquery, arrays, function

How to make array in function with options to run.
This is declaration:

```
$(".object").myfunction({
    run1: 'spell',
    run2: true
});
```

Here is function:

```
$.fn.myfunction= function() {
    alert(run1);
};
```

How to alert the run1 or run2 from declaration ?

Comment: Why would you want to do that? why are you adding functionality to the base jQuery object if the functionality *doesn't* use the object?

Comment: @Amit That is only example, I am building sth more :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add an object for the function to receive

```
$.fn.myfunction= function(params) {
    alert(params.run1);
};
```

Comment: @Mergars, is the function declaration before or after the invocation?

Comment: Can you tell me, how spell function without params or with params (2 functions on 1 page) It's desn't works with your result.

Comment: javascript cannot overload functions in the way you are suggesting. If you try - only the last will work. What you can do - is check what you have received, i.e. `if (params === undefined){/*code for no params*/}else{/*code with params*/}`

Answer (score 1):

My proposal is:

```js
$.fn.myfunction= function(obj, key) {
  alert(obj[key]);
  /*****
            $.each(obj, function(index, element) {
               alert("Key: " + index + " Value: " + element);
            });
             *****/
};
$(function () {
  $(".object").myfunction({
    run1: 'spell',
    run2: true
  }, 'run1');
});
```

```html
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.js"></script>


<button class="object" style="visibility:hidden">Click Me</button>
```

Comment: @Mergars Thanks so much in any case. I updated my snippet.

Comment: No problem, but you created function with only 2 params. Thanks again :)

Comment: It's a pleasure to cooperate. Thanks so much